# SQL/BigQuery - How to eliminate duplicates based on two columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with the list of items sold together within a sales database:

```
original_SKU  bought_with  quantity
12345         98765        130
98765         12345        130
abcde         fghij        88
fghij         abcde        88
```

however you can see that the combinations are repeated... apparently an easy command but I'm having difficulties lol

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select any_value(struct(original_SKU, bought_with)).*, sum(quantity) quantity
from your_table
group by least(original_SKU, bought_with) || greatest(original_SKU, bought_with)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]